# The network adapter could not establish the connection sql developer remote

Tags: oracle11g

```
In Remote the connection is Establish successfully.

But When i try local i am getting the Network adapter could not establish the connection.
```

Details

I have the following information:

Port 1521 is not open for either server when I telnet
My listener is up and running for both.
I can access derp-db.derp.edu on Oracle SQL Developer.
Oracle client is on my local machine + Oracle SQL Developer

I can remote desktop to both servers

```
**listener.ora**

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.9.80.94)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app


**lsnrctl status :**
```

Listner is Up to date`enter code here`

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                21-OCT-2014 09:38:17
Uptime                    0 days 2 hr. 27 min. 6 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   D:\app\kul_ahamed\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admi
n\listener.ora
Listener Log File         d:\app\kul_ahamed\diag\tnslsnr\KUL-BU3-E037\listener\a
lert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=KUL-BU3-E037.incontrol-tech.local)(P
ORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Need to improve clarity of question to ensure community can assist you better